# Loop for generate weeks of year not always correct

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to iterate through all weeks in a date range (from monday to sunday):

```
function getInfoWeeks($date_start, $date_end) {
   $start    = new DateTime($date_start);
   $start2    = new DateTime($date_end);
   $year_number = $start->format('Y');
   $end      = new DateTime($data_fine);
   $interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
   $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
   foreach ($period as $date) {
      $week = new stdClass();
      $firstday = $start -> setISODate( $year_number, (int)$date -> format('W'), 1 ); 
      $lastday = $start2 -> setISODate( $year_number, (int)$date -> format('W'), 7 ); 
      $week -> period = $date->format('d-m-Y');
      $week -> month = strftime("%B", $date -> getTimestamp());
      $week -> monthNr = (int)$date -> format('m');
      $week -> nr = $date -> format('W');
      $week -> firstday = $firstday->format('d-m-Y');
      $week -> lastday = $lastday->format('d-m-Y');
      $week -> year_number = $year_number;
      $array_week[] = $week;
   }
return $array_week;}
```

For getInfoWeeks("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31") is correct and I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [period] => 01-01-2020
            [month] => gennaio
            [monthNr] => 1
            [nr] => 01
            [firstday] => 30-12-2019
            [lastday] => 05-01-2020
            [year_number] => 2020
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [period] => 08-01-2020
            [month] => gennaio
            [monthNr] => 1
            [nr] => 02
            [firstday] => 06-01-2020
            [lastday] => 12-01-2020
            [year_number] => 2020
        )...
```

But for getInfoWeeks("2021-01-01", "2021-12-31") is wrong for array[0] because there is 2022:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [period] => 01-01-2021
            [month] => gennaio
            [monthNr] => 1
            [nr] => 53
            [firstday] => 03-01-2022
            [lastday] => 09-01-2022
            [year_number] => 2021
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [period] => 08-01-2021
            [month] => gennaio
            [monthNr] => 1
            [nr] => 01
            [firstday] => 04-01-2021
            [lastday] => 10-01-2021
            [year_number] => 2021
        )
    ...
```

Why for 2020 is ok and for 2021 (and also 2022) is wrong?
Where's the mistake?

Comment: `$end      = new DateTime($data_fine);` Where is `$data_fine` set?

Comment: Mea culpa... `$end = new DateTime($data_end);`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `$date->format('W')` does not do what you think. 2021-01-01 produces week 53, not 1. DateTime is a mess.

```
function getInfoWeeks($date_start, $date_end) {
  $start    = new DateTime($date_start);
  $start2    = new DateTime($date_end);
  $year_number = $start->format('Y');
  $end      = new DateTime($date_end);
  $interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
  $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
  $weekNumber = 1;
  foreach ($period as $date) {
      echo $date->format('Y-m-d') .  ' week ' . (int)$date -> format('W'). "\n";
      $week = new stdClass();
      // $firstday = $start -> setISODate( $year_number, (int)$date -> format('W'), 1 ); 
      // $lastday = $start2 -> setISODate( $year_number, (int)($date -> format('W')), 7 ); 
      $date2 = clone $date;
      $date2->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));

      $week -> period = $date->format('d-m-Y');
      $week -> month = $date->format('m');//strftime("%B", $date -> getTimestamp());
      $week -> monthNr = (int)$date -> format('m');
      $week -> nr = $weekNumber++;
      // I switched the format to make the debug output easier to read
      $week -> firstday = $date->format('Y-m-d');
      $week -> lastday = $date2->format('Y-m-d');
      $week -> year_number = $year_number;
      $array_week[] = $week;
  }
    return $array_week;
}
$a = getInfoWeeks("2021-01-01", "2021-12-31");
print_r($a);
```

As an added bonus, here is how you do it with Carbon.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2020-01-01', '7 days', '2020-12-31');
foreach ($period as $key => $date) {
    if ($key) {
        echo ', ';
    }
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $date2 = $date->copy()->addDays(6);
    echo ' - ' . $date2->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Install Carbon with composer or get it from https://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: Ok, but I need the first week start with monday, so to get `[nr] => 01
            [firstday] => 04-01-2021
            [lastday] => 10-01-2021`

Comment: "DateTime is a mess" no it isn't. If you have a method to divide 365 days into an integer number of 7-day weeks I'd love to hear it. `W` is the [ISO8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) which is a well defined spec and includes the provision for years with 53 weeks, sometimes called "Leap Weeks".

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where I'm wrong, so to solve I added this condition

> `foreach ($period as $date) {
>       $i++; 
>       ... 
>       if ($i == 1 && $week->nr = 53) continue;`

... it's not very elegant but it works